# RHEL 8 , sssd - Could not start TLS encryption EE certificate key too weak

Tags: linux, rhel, sssd

In my RedHat 8.4 server, after joining AD when I start the sssd process its giving below error message.

```
sssd[be[XXX.XXX.XXX]][23324]: Could not start TLS encryption. error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (EE certificate key too weak)
```

Here is sssd config file:

```
domains = XXX.XXX.XXX
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/XXX.XXX.XXX]
ad_enable_gc = False
ad_use_ldaps = True
dns_resolver_timeout = 15    .
ldap_network_timeout = 15
ad_domain = XXX.XXX.XXX
dyndns_update = false
krb5_realm = XXX.XXX.XXX
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = False
fallback_homedir = /home/%u
access_provider = simple
 
debug_level = 2

[nss]
#debug_level = 9

[pam]
#debug_level = 9
```

how to clear this error message?

Thanks

Comment: The error message is telling you what the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

Your system is configured, either by default or through policy, to require a certain level of security for TLS.  Usually that level of security is 112 bits or 128 bits.  This message means the certificate for the remote server is too weak and the key should be larger (either 2048 bits for a 112-bit security level or 3072 bits for a 128-bit security level).

This message can also occur if you're using a proxy or TLS middlebox of some sort, since the key for that can also be too small.

In general, you should solve this problem by making sure the server to which you are connecting is using either a 256-bit or larger ECDSA or a 3072-bit or larger RSA key.  Those both provide a 128-bit security level, which is the minimum level of security considered acceptable these days.

If your problem is a TLS middlebox, you should remove it from your network.  They often have bugs that lead to security vulnerabilities and are known to break various software.

Only if you cannot avoid it should you change the security settings, which [has been explained in this ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/1033354/how-to-diagnose-ca-certificate-too-weak-error-how-to-use-the-ca-cert-anyway).